# Reporting when Missing Values are present

Tags: missing-data, reporting

I'm looking for rule of best practice. When it comes to business reporting, is it best to report the number/presence of null values, or to find a number such as an average to replace them? The variable considered here is $Volume, summed over time. So, I'm reporting on the past, not creating a model, and am very hesitant to report a number that I know is not reflective of the actual data, only possibly close.

I'm thinking that in this case I should NOT replace the nulls as I might do when creating a model, but am in a situation where I am being asked to do so anyway.

fyi these are "missing" and if a problem is corrected, they will no longer be missing. Another reason I would rather wait for the real data.

Advice on best practice is highly appreciated!